# how to hide overlay help datapoints outside range in grafana2

Tags: grafana

I have been using grafana2 this days and it is a wonderful tool for visualization, thanks for the creator, and I wonder if I can remove the guide/help in graph "Datapoints outside time range"

query for querying all series, base from the examples. I'm not pro in `influxdb` yet, so my query could be wrong.

`select temperature from /.*/ group by time(7d)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was caused by incorrect query:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/1913

Comment: thanks for the comment!, but I have multiple series, I'm new using grafana2. and I dont want to manually type my series names in query.. I'll edit my post to show my query. thank you again!